# Powerset combinations of columns from Data Frame

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a dataframe df with 4 columns 0,1,2,3.

I want to combine these columns via a powerset list (xlist):

```
mylist = (0,1,2,3)

xlist=[]
for e in adjusted_powerset(mylist):
    xlist.append(e)

xlist = [(0,1),(0,2),(1,2)...(0,1,2,3)]
```

creating a dataframe df2 as a subset of df using column index numbers from the powerset.

I then perform a calcuation on df2, get some results and repeat via a loop.

Where I am stuck is how to index df using the xlist as a filter.

My iloc is as follows:

```
for j in range(1,len(mylist)):
    df2 = df.iloc[:,[xlist[j][0],xlist[j][1]]]
```

the column portion of xlist has to be dynamic so has [xlist[j][0],xlist[j][1]] when the xlist row has 2 values, and [xlist[j][0],xlist[j][1], xlist[j][2]] when it has 3 and so on up to k (in this case, 4).

I realise this is probably simple and am prepared to be tutted at.  Is .join the way forward. what is the best way to set this up assuming k can be quite large.

Many thanks

Comment: To clarify my question above: How do I convert xlist above to a list of lists. ie replace the '(' with '[' and make it a list?

Answer (score 0):

This creates a list of lists that can be used to filter the df:

```
for e in adjusted_powerset(mylist):
    e = list(e)    
    xlist.append(e)
```